# Python code, to copy data from certain cells in one xls workbook, and paste it into certain cells in another xls workbook

Tags: python, excel

The source workbook will have input data at random but fixed cells (say A1,C2,E3...). 
The python code should copy these data one by one (/at one stretch) and paste it into a different workbook's fixed row (say paste all the copied data onto raw#2) .

Please help.

Comment: Which is your question? It isn't clear, you need some sample code? if so, OS is not the best place for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't provide code for you based on the limited information you provided, but hopefully I can point you in the right direction.

There are a few python libraries that can do this. One solution involves xlwt and xlrd. 
These are fairly easy to deal with and although they are limited in their scope, they should be able to handle what you are doing. 
(see: http://www.python-excel.org/ for download and documentation)

If you need more functionality I'd point you in the way of win32com, but in this case, it does seem a bit of overkill for what you are looking for. 
(see: http://pythonexcels.com/basic-excel-driving-with-python/ for examples and http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/ for download)